# What does it mean to spread a function. Are normal functions iterable in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, spread-syntax

I am doing something like the below code in console

```
function add(a,b){return a+b;};
const obj = {...add};
```

To my surprise it doesn't throw an error. And neither do

```
const obj = {...123};
```

Spread syntax should be applicable to only iterable entities like objects, arrays, string, map, set, etc.
So why does it doesn't throw an error when using non-iterable entities?
Or am I missing something here?

Comment: In pre-ES2018 specification era, you would be correct. However, with the release of ES2018 came [spread syntax for object initializers](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-object-initializer).

Answer (score 7):

Functions in JavaScript are also `objects`. It has it's own properties like `name`, `call`, `apply` and others.

Doing `const obj = {...add}` just gets the *enumerable* properties of the `function object`, put them into another object and assigns to the `obj`. You can check via

```js
function add(a,b){return a+b;};
add.test = 1;

const obj = {...add};

console.log('test' in obj);
```

What about `123` it is converted to the `Number` wrapper and the rest is the same

```js
const obj = {...123};

console.log('valueOf' in obj);
```

Comment: See also CopyDataProperties in the spec text: https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/2018/#sec-copydataproperties The source object in `{...source}` is converted to an object at the start of the spread operation.

Comment: @surenSrapyan this is not a very good example. 
console.log('valueOf' in obj);
will return true in any case as each object already has it.
Where as for code like

function add(){};
const obj = {...add};
console.log('call' in obj)
will return false even though it exists in the prototype chain.
Using spread operator as above iterates only for own properties.

Comment: The word *iterable* is a bit misleading as it implies that all Objects are iterable, which they are not. Object spread works on *enumerable* properties

Comment: @CodingIntrigue Updated. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

What you have is a [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) for object literals (which is not supported in all [user agents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Browser_compatibility)).

> #### Spread in object literals
>
> The [Rest/Spread Properties for ECMAScript](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) proposal (stage 4) adds spread properties to [object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer). It copies own enumerable properties from a provided object onto a new object.

```js
function add(a, b) { return a + b; }

const obj = { ...add };

console.log(obj); // no properties because no own enumerable properties
```

Comment: Also illustrative: if you insert `add.foo = "bar"`, it is easy to see `obj` prints as `{foo: "bar"}`. It just so happens by default functions have no iterable props.

Comment: I don't think this is correct.
If you do 
```
function add(a, b) { return a + b; }

const obj = { ...add };

console.log('call' in obj)
```
It returns false, which should be true by your logic

Comment: @Amadan explains it.
The snippet you provided will not work if you do console.log('call' in obj)
Although it is available in the function prototype chain.
Default functions have no iterable props.

Comment: i have change the answer.

Comment: @Amadan can you explain a bit on situation like const obj = {...123}